# seeking methods to Wipe page the moment (<1 sec) JavaScript is disabled

Tags: php, security, wordpress, client-server

the context: while content and copy protection is practically a moot point, and I've heard every argument there is about right-context menu disable, the state of the art is to secure a page with JavaScript measures, and then *somehow* create a Page wipe  if the security is bypassed by disabling JavaScript.

Another way to say this is "make the content depend on continuous availability of JavaScript". My target is a page wipe initiated within 1 second of JavaScript being disabled.

The methods I'm exploring are PHP for WordPress...and I'm considering initiating a process on page load which wipes the page *unless* a JavaScript token is present to stop the process. I also thought of a method which starts a process server side to rewrite the page content if err status can be proven to show JS disabled.

Comment: Since you cannot detect if JavaScript is disabled from the server, and you cannot "wipe the page" without JavaScript, you cannot do this. Even if you could, somebody can always just curl domain.com and get the source code.

Comment: You can spend hundreds of work hours coming up with a contrivance like this, and the hacker who wants to do whatever you're trying to prevent can spend 15 minutes to work around *any* JavaScript security measures.

Comment: As far as obfuscation goes: You can use `<noscript>` and absolutely position an oversized `<div>` in it that blanks out everything.

Comment: Right so nobody's interested in pushing the envelope where this is concerned. @spudley- I do understand and I simply don't care what the tools are. I can and will meet my goals. Obviously not with your help. I wonder if people stuck with Flash for video if there'd ever be an HTML 5...

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @alessioalex. What you're asking for is not possible.

The only possible way to continuously monitor anything on a web page is with Javascript. And the only way to change the page content after page load is with Javascript. And if I've got Firebug installed (or the developer tools for any other browser), I can see the entire content of your site, and even alter your Javascript while it's running. I don't even need to turn Javascript off to disable your protection feature.

There is a *very limited* amount of protection you can get from the basic "disable context menu" function. It isn't secure, but it does protect you against people who don't know what they're doing or who can't be bothered to waste their time getting past it.

But there is zero additional protection to be had from doing anything more than that in a browser environment, because all your code and graphics are available and it is trivial for a user with even limited knowledge to get at it.

If someone knows enough to try switching off Javascript (and if they're determined enough to get at your code to do that) then you've already lost the battle.

You say you've heard every argument about copy protection on the web, but if you're asking this question you clearly haven't understood those arguments.

Bottom line: If copy protection is that important to you, then a web page is the wrong environment for your content.

Comment: Excellent answers all- thank very much. My qualifying comment didn't post which states I need to make this Uber-hassle for the average gremmie to scrape the content. I am fully aware of the ways to currently beat any protection, so I need to create the next-better-mousetrap. It's a matter of degrees, not solving the impossible.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to protect, but right now if you really need it protected, keep it off the web. Unfortunately, the average 'gremmie' knows how to use firebug, which renders any browser-based 'protection' attempt completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yep, no doubt. I'll revisit the post with my results- maybe set up a "how fast can you hack this" for some reward...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not something you are looking for, since the workaround for this technique would be to use IE, but in the future one could use [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) to schedule "disappearance" of the content and reset it with JS periodically :)

Comment: Hmmm, like this thinking, particularly using CSS - currently I have a basic implementation of an AJAX callback which - on error - results in different behavior from the server. In other words- if the right handshake doesn't occur on the response - such as JavaScript disabled, PHP will yield a different result, such as resetting the "page." The Page is an application which does not demo   critical content on the outset, and requires j
Q

Comment: (cont.) jQuery to display properly. So the URL can be had without compromise... it's a total contrivance, just not 100 hrs. worth :)

Comment: It's probably poor etiquette to stack my own responses, but it's even worse to treat a coder as if he doesn't know what he's talking about. i asked for solutions and a discussion about methods that were 1 apart from what is currently done. Just because it's horribly unpopular to restrict web content, when my client or someday *your* client has tons of public content and 1 paid Training Course, you too will be thinking of the next better mousetrap to secure pages. Just because there are expert thieves in the world doesn't mean you neglect to put a lock on your front door :)